# How could we use one search results in another search using sub search query?

Tags: splunk-query

Query :

```
search event_name=email OR event |where NOT LIKE(person_id,"%WF%")| stats dc(person_id)
```

Result :

> 618bd8ea-59dc-485f-a0a3-908adb804443
>
> 6618bb54-73fd-4d13-b2e2-72e18171a904
>
> WF724ad888-cbd4-483f-91b3-01a95809ad7b
>
> WF9e9f0ec6-899e-43a8-b1e3-ca158516b6f

I need to use this above result again in same query to get those records count which are **not starting with "WF"**.

Please suggest .

Any help would be really appreciated.